# Renderscript: Restrictions on writes to global variables for gpu compute

Tags: android, gpgpu, renderscript

I am using Nexus 10, Android 4.4. I see that if I have writes to global variables in the script, then the script is executed on CPU, instead of GPU. I can see this from logcat mali driver prints.

I read somewhere that this limitation will go away in future. I was hoping 4.4 will remove this. Does anyone know more about why this limitation exists and when it might go away?

This limitation appears to be restrictive. For instance, I am using an intermittent allocation as a global variable between kernels in a scriptgroup, and my script guarantees that the kernels write at different locations in the allocation. Due to this restriction, my script now falls back to CPU, which causes significant performance delays in atleast a few cases. For instance, this performance loss is significant if one uses cosine, pow functions in the kernel. CPU(s) do a far worse job than GPU on these functions